# To validate and connvert entered phone number in a form

Tags: javascript, regex, html

I am working on an HTML form which has 4 fields as below

```
Name
Email
Phone Number
Message
```

The field for phone number should accept 10 digits. It change/accept of the format `(xxx) xxx-xxxx` when i click on the Message field.

I have written the function for javascript to do so but the number is not getting changed when i click on the message field. The code is below

It would be a great help if someone could help me out with this. Thanks in advance!

```
function PhoneValidation(phone) {
  if (!(this.isNull)) {

    var str = this.rawValue;

    var regExp = /^\d{10}$/;

    if (regExp.test(str)) {

      this.rawValue = "(" + str.substr(0, 3) + ") " + str.substr(3, 3) + "-" + str.substr(6, 4);

    } else {

      regExp = /^[1-9]\d{2}\s\d{3}\s\d{4}$/;

      if (regExp.test(str)) {

        this.rawValue = "(" + str.substr(0, 3) + ") " + str.substr(4, 3) + "-" + str.substr(8, 4);

      } else {

        regExp = /^\([1-9]\d{2}\)\s?\d{3}\-\d{4}$/;

        if (!(regExp.test(str))) {

          xfa.host.messageBox("Please enter the telephone number in the format '(999) 999-9999'.");

          this.rawValue = null;

          xfa.host.setFocus(this);

        }

      }

    }

  }
}
```

And HTML below:

```
<form id="contact-form" class="contact-form" method="post" action="">
    <div class="result"></div>
    <input type="text" name="contact[name]" id="name" placeholder="Name *">
    <input type="text" name="contact[email]" id="email" placeholder="E-mail *">
    <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" placeholder="Phone" onChange="PhoneValidation(this)" ;>
    <textarea cols="5" rows="5" name="contact[message]" id="message" placeholder="Message *"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" class="btn-dark" value="SEND">
</form>
```

Comment: What is `this.rawValue`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your `validate` function `this = window`, or something else so I have no idea what will `!this.isNull` actually do.

You may change it to something like

```
function PhoneValidation(phone) {
   if(phone.value) {
         // set up the phone.value here
   }
}
// bind the change event as you did.
<input type="text" name="phone" id="phone"  placeholder="Phone" onChange="PhoneValidation(this)";>
```

**EDIT**  The code above is just the idea, please note that inside PhoneValidation in your case `this = window`. You have passed phone so try to use it, you can take the demo here http://jsfiddle.net/7qjz2/. As a summary

```
window.PhoneValidation = function(phone)
// cause I don't know where you put this js, so let bind it to window.
```

Next in side function, `rawValue` is undefined so use `phone.value` instead
If you can't pass the condition, set the html for your message div. by

```
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Whatever you want"
```

That's all. Hope this help!

Comment: @user3422826 I have update my answer, you can take a look, it worked.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (!(this.isNull)) {
```

Apparently, keep it short and simple like:

```
if (this) {
```

Comment: @simpletron Ok, thanks, I didn't find `this` modified anywhere that's why.